# Why does using Rows.Count only find the first 12 rows of data?

Tags: excel, count, range, vba

I'm trying to find the rows with data in my source data sheet and then copy some of the columns into various places in my destination worksheet using VBA. I have successfully done this for a list with 12k lines but when I do some test data, it only copies the first 12 rows out of 19 rows of data....

```
Sub Header_Raw()
Dim dataBook As Workbook
Dim Header_Raw As Worksheet, Header As Worksheet
Dim dataSource As Range, dataDest As Range
Dim sourceDataRowCount As Integer, index As Integer

Set dataBook = Application.ThisWorkbook
Set sheetSource = dataBook.Sheets("Header_Raw")
Set sheetDest = dataBook.Sheets("Header")

Set dataSource = sheetSource.Range("B4", _
                sheetSource.Range("J90000").End(xlUp))
sourceDataRowCount = dataSource.Rows.Count

Set dataDest = sheetDest.Range("B13", "B" & _
                            sourceDataRowCount)

For index = 1 To sourceDataRowCount
  dataDest(index, 1).Value = dataSource(index, 1).Value
  dataDest(index, 2).Value = dataSource(index, 2).Value

Next index

End Sub
```

If you can help tell me what I have done wrong, that would be great
thanks
Julie

Comment: This is a very vague question. I don't really know what you have in your input data and what exactly you are trying to achieve. Maybe it is because your data source is starting from `B4` instead of `B1`, maybe its because your `datadest` is from `B13`. At least you will need to give us the input data and what exactly you wanted to select in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps column J only has 12 rows populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your life a bit easier with simple debugging. Run the following:

```
Sub HeaderRaw()

    'Dim all the variables here

    Set dataBook = Application.ThisWorkbook
    Set SheetSource = dataBook.Sheets("Header_Raw")
    Set sheetDest = dataBook.Sheets("Header")

    Set dataSource = SheetSource.Range("B4", SheetSource.Range("J90000").End(xlUp))
    SheetSource.Activate
    dataSource.Select

End Sub
```

Now you will see what is your `dataSource`, as far as it is selected. Probably it is not what you expect.

Comment: Hi,OK, both comments really helped.  So firstly I ran the debugging to see what was highlighted and it only highlighted B4: J16 even though there is data down to row 22.

Comment: Apologies... pressed return too early...
I also noticed that the rows below row 16 in column J are blank
What I want to do is set the range to be all rows with data in column B, regardless of whether there are blank cells in the other columns
Does that make sense?

Comment: @Yorkshire - cool. So the problem is that you need to get the last row with data. And this is usually not done the way you do it. Check this:https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: @Yorkshire - change `J90000` with `B90000` in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much, changing the J90000 to B90000 did the trick... I understand now, I had thought that I needed to identify J as I am including those columns in the offset but as this is solely counting the non blank rows I only need B... thank you :)